# viewchild nativeElement is undefined if content is wrapped up with ngif

Tags: angular

I was trying to draw a line using canvas, which is wrapped up with a `ngif` condition.

```html
<canvas *ngIf="condition" #canvas></canvas>
<button (click)="draw()"> click Me</button>
```

Now via `ViewChild`, I would like to draw a line. Code looks like that:

```js
  condition: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('canvas', {static: false}) public canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  draw() {
    this.condition = true;
    var ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(100,0);
    ctx.lineTo(100,100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

> ERROR
> Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I have seen that, if I remove the `ngif` then canvas rendering is working fine. I could not understand why it is not working while using `ngif`. Can someone please explain, how to fix that code?

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ar8lz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set `condition` to `true` and immediatelly tries to access `this.canvas`, which is still `undefined`, as the changes are still not computed.

I can see two possible solutions for this:

The 1st. **ugly** solution is to wrap it in a `setTimeout`:

```
  constructor(private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  draw() {
    this.condition = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      const ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
      ctx.stroke();
    });
  }
```

Another one is to call [**`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges):

```
  constructor(private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  draw() {
    this.condition = true;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    const ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdrsm7)

Answer (score 1):

When `this.condition` is false the `canvas` would not exist and the property `@ViewChild('canvas', {static: false}) public canvas` would be undefined.

I see in the `draw` method the `this.condition` is assigned to `true`. Angular would run a change detection cycle after the function would be executed. So, the canvas would appear after the `draw` function would be executed while I see the code tries to draw on the canvas before it.

To fix it you might add the timeout, eg:

```js
  draw() {
    this.condition = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        var ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(100,0);
        ctx.lineTo(100,100);
        ctx.stroke();
    }, 0)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

With

```
condition: boolean = false;
```

you do your condition 'false', then doesn't exist all this:

```
<canvas *ngIf="condition" #canvas>
  
</canvas>
```

, so **#canvas** doesn't exits neither.
Then, in the ts code component, the childview ('canvas') is undefined. This is the reason.

Comment: While clicking on the button I am setting it to true. check the draw function please @juan-berzosa-tejero

Comment: You change the vaule of condition after the view is created (as you said, when you click on the button), but for the creation of the component (in The AfterViewInit Lifecycle Hook), it didn't exit, so you can't referer it.

Comment: Maybe if you force the changedetection before: import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { ... }     draw() {
    this.condition = true;
    setTimeout(() => {this.ref.markForCheck();
        var ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(100,0);
        ctx.lineTo(100,100);
        ctx.stroke();
    }, 0)
  } @developer033 just give you the same answerd, I didn't see before, sorry.